# How can I fix high ping?

Tags: world-of-pirate-ships

How can I lower my ping when it is too high while playing World of Pirate Ships? This is the first time I have experienced this in this game. I don't know what to do or how to fix it.

Answer (score 3):

Your ping if is the delay between sending a request to the server and getting an answer back.

As a general rule, there are a few things you can do/check to get the best ping you can possibly have.

First, make sure that you have no download running on your device and network. These will limit how much data is received by the game.

Make sure that you have good connectivity to your router if you are connected through wifi or that you have good LTE/3G/4G connection with your mobile device.

Other than that, it might be a good idea to contact your ISP to get a better internet connection.

Answer (score 2):

An extension to TheBird956's answer:

You can check if there are different sever for different regions. If you are located in the US and you are playing on a server in Europe, it's normal to have a high ping, so rather play on servers in your region.
If the game has a server browser you can check the ping you'll have on this server. It will be displayed somewhere  in its list entry.

Answer (score 0):

Ping is the time taken to send and receive data from client to server, so to reduce lag (ping), try closing background applications first, then close all internet used application, phones, tablets, PC, Mac, etc. then be sure to port forward the application or game. If that doesn't work, try upgrading your internet speed.